# Ipad pro showing blank screen and A RenderFlex overflowed by 453 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, overflow, flutter-renderflex-error

i'm trying to test flutter app on ipad pro in debug mode and showing error of "A RenderFlex overflowed by 453 pixels on the right." and if i use singlechildlistview then show blank screen.

Here is the code:

```dart
child: SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      SvgPicture.asset(
        "assets/icons/ic_location.svg",
        height: 24,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 5,
      ),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: Get.width / 4,
                height: 12,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: color,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                color: Colors.black,
                size: 16,
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Container(
            width: Get.width - 100,
            height: 12,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: color, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Please provide the full code

Answer (score 0):

Parent of `SingleChildScrollView` is needed to give a solution.

But I can assume, you have some other widget at the left to show, which causing the issue.

Remove `SingleChildScrollView` from the child and Wrap the parent widget with `SingleChildScrollView`.